# How to make dynamic the li element hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I got a way to solve my problem in my navigation of my site `http://204.197.252.143/~paterson/` , that when I hover the link (li-element) the background will set into gray and the background-image (cross sign) of the previous element will hide also. My question is, Is there another way to make it dynamically? This is my code. Any help are appreciated.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-21").hover(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-23").css("background", "transparent");
        });
        $("li#menu-item-21").mouseleave(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-23").css("background", "url(http://site.com/
        ~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
         });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-23").hover(function () {
         $("li#menu-item-22").css("background", "transparent");
        });
        $("li#menu-item-23").mouseleave(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-22").css("background", "url(http://site.com/
        ~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-23").hover(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-22").css("background", "transparent");
        });
        $("li#menu-item-23").mouseleave(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-22").css("background", "url(http://site.com/
        ~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
    });</script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-20").hover(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-96").css("background", "transparent");
        });
        $("li#menu-item-20").mouseleave(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-96").css("background", "url(http://site.com/
        ~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
    });</script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-19").hover(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-20").css("background", "transparent");
        });
        $("li#menu-item-19").mouseleave(function () {
       $("li#menu-item-20").css("background", "url(http://site.com/
       ~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
    });</script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-96").hover(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-21").css("background", "transparent");
        });

        $("li#menu-item-96").mouseleave(function () {
        $("li#menu-item-21").css("background", "url(http://site.com/~paterson/
         wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you not using CSS for this?

Comment: ^^ What he said, just changing the background would just require a few lines of CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **.hover()** and **.prev()** in jQuery to do this.

**Here's the code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("li.menu").hover(function () {
          $(this).prev().css("background", "transparent");
        }, function(){
          $(this).prev().css("background", "url(http://site.com/~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png) no-repeat right");
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tank you. Your answer really help me :-)

Answer (score 1):

like @juno said.. why not use css? 
for example:

```
li:hover{ attributes to change }
```

Answer (score 0):

rejig your html a little so that the background image appears to the left the li. Something like:

```
# put the background image on the left of the LI's
.nav-menu li { background: url("http://204.197.252.143/~paterson/wp-content/themes/patersons/img/cross.png") no-repeat center left;

# remove the background image from the first element
.nav-menu li:first-child { background: none }

#when you're hovering, remove the background
.nav-menu li:hover { background: transparent; }
```

Something like that will work without any JS.

edit:: when you come to launching, make sure your image paths are relative from the CSS document - url(../img/cross.png) - rather than hardcoding to the IP address.